# Using two classes with same name in java

Tags: java, import, package

I know this question has been asked a lot on importing two classes and instead omitting the import for both and calling full path whenever you want to use.
My question related to this is can we just import one, use that one without the full path and write the full path of the other.

e.g.

```
import com.stackoverflow.FirstOne


firstOne ok = new FirstOne();
com.another.folder.firstOne isthisOk = new firstOne();
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible :) Infact `imports` are just to make developer life simple. Internally Java represents everything with fully qualified.

Comment: Yes, you can, why not

Comment: Is there any reason not to just try this for yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a new object with a full package as well:

```
import com.stackoverflow.FirstOne;

FirstOne ok = new FirstOne(); 
com.another.folder.FirstOne isthisOk = new com.another.folder.FirstOne();
```

Note: Case is important

Answer (score 1):

Yes...that works.

You can use any number of classes by fully qualified name - and then import one to use by short name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is posible if the class belongs to different packages, because the static type of the object is the name of a package + the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, as log as you avoid confusing compiler, it will be happy.